# Prevent log when domain is duplicate in php?

Tags: php, logging, duplicates

I have a simple php script hosted on my server with a function to log all the domains who call the script remotely (to benefit from some functions I provide for free). Here is my log function

```
    $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; // Get hostname who uses this script  
    $file = '/home/username/public_html/includes/user_logs.log';
    $logData = file_get_contents($file);
      if(strpos($logData, $host) === false) {
        if(!empty($host))
            file_put_contents($file, $host.PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
      }
```

It's working good but how can I prevent file append when the domain is duplicate ?

right now the log file gets very huge in a matter of seconds because the script logs all internal pages of the domains who use the script ( millions of internal pages !! Edit : to clarify , I get only few domains daily but some domains are really huge with thousands of internal pages and I don't want to log all of that! )

I want to log each domain only one time ( one page is enough ) and prevent further logging from the same domain after that so only new domains get logged.

Comment: A flat file isn't really the appropriate approach if you've truly got millions of domains to log. Something like Redis would be much better there.

Comment: @ceejayoz Not really , I don't have millions of domains just a few domains daily. But some domains are huge with thousands of pages and the script log every single page of them !!! that's why I want to prevent this and log each domain only one time.

Comment: You would need to parse the log file and any rotated ones, into an array then search for the match.. not efficient, especially working with fs. Store in db, if no db then sqlite, if not support for that then store as json, so its easier to parse/query.